# Updating lights on Corsair RGB keyboard with AutoHotKey

Tags: windows, keyboard, autohotkey

I'd like to change the lights on my Corsair RGB keyboard based on an ImageSearch with autohotkey. I've already got the first part down: searching for an image within the Dota 2 window and returning MsgBoxes based on the result. Now, I'd like to update the colors of certain keys on the keyboard based on those results.

I don't think this is possible directly from the scripting language, but I want to know if there is a program out there that can talk to the keyboard and if I can control that with AHK. Cheers!

Comment: See these scripts: [one](http://autohotkey.com/board/topic/9587-keyboard-led-control-capslocknumlockscrolllock-lights/), [two](http://ahkscript.org/forum/viewtopic.php?p=353629), [three](https://www.reddit.com/r/AutoHotkey/comments/2jghx5/need_help_with_keyboard_led_script/) (found them by googling `autohotkey blink keyboard led`)

Comment: These are for the num/caps/scroll lights, the Corsair RGB has LEDs under every key and are controlled by a custom program.

Comment: Oh, cool keyboard! See [LibCorsairRGB](https://github.com/Palmr/LibCorsairRGB). There's a prebuilt dll which you may invoke via `DllCall` in AutoHotkey.